# Room + RxJava2 case with infinite loop

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using the new Android persistance lib, Room, with RxJava2. The following code is causing an infinite loop. If I comment out the line that updates the user in the second observable it works fine. If I leave it there, the onNext method of the first observable will be called on and on again.

Does Room requery the table when an entity is updated? If so, why is it publishing the message again on the same stream? Is this intended behavior? Is it a bug in the library?

```
val userDao = HeyHeyApp.database.userDao();
userDao.getAll()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ listOfUsers ->
        if (!listOfUsers.isEmpty()) {
           HeyHeyApp.currentUser = listOfUsers.first()
           HeyHeyApp.currentUser.fcmDeviceId = getDeviceId()

           Single.fromCallable({
               HeyHeyApp.database.userDao()
                  .updateUser(HeyHeyApp.currentUser)
           }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe({ _ ->
             })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you subscribes for userDao.getAll() event - Room will trigger your observer onNext() method each time when databases data is changed. And next in your onNext() method you change the data in database:

```
 Single.fromCallable({
           HeyHeyApp.database.userDao()
              .updateUser(HeyHeyApp.currentUser)
       }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe({ _ ->
         })
```

and after that Room call your onNext() method again... and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work by calling take(1) before subscribing!